# code behind ASPX page is not executing js code

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have an .aspx page with VB.NET, in this page I only run a query and create and export a Excel file. In some part of the code I'm trying to execute any JS code (alert, console.log, etc.) and I tried in different ways for example:

- Response.Write
- ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript
- lblJavaScript.Text = "<*script type='text/javascript'>execute();<*/script>".

But none of the above options works.

My code behind is something like this:

```
Public Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    Try
        CreateExcel()
    Catch ex as Exception
    Finally
        '' Kill other process
    End Try
End Sub

Public Sub CreateExcel()
    '' Do a lot of things for example run a query, open a write on an Excel file, etc...

    '' This function has a lot of importance I will explain why below
    DownloadReport(oExcel, "MyExcelFile.xlsx", Response)

    Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>console.log('Hello 0');</script>")
End Sub
```

**IMPORTANT**: Debugging step by step my code I found that if I delete or comment DownloadReport line my JS code is executed, so I almost sure that the problem is with this function.

DownloadReport code:

```
Public Sub DownloadReport(ByVal app As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application, ByVal Filename As String, ByRef Response As HttpResponse)
    Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>console.log('Hello 1');</script>")
    Dim bytesInStream As Byte() = GetActiveWorkbook(app)
    '' I know that Response.Clear deletes the above Response.Write
    Response.Clear()

    '' If I comment the above lines the Js on Response.Write also works
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & Filename)
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", (bytesInStream.Length))
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
    Response.BinaryWrite(bytesInStream)
    HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()
    Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>console.log('Hello 2');</script>")
End Sub
```

If I comment DownloadReport on my console I will see Hello 0.

If I comment the 5 lines on DownloadReport function on my console I will see Hello 2 and Hello 0 on that order.

If I not comment anything I will not see anything on console and also no js error message.

What's wrong with my code and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The header `"Content-Disposition:attachment; filename=filename"` tells your browser to save the response as a file rather than render it as a HTML.
Open the downloaded file in a text editor,you will see `script` tag at the end.

Comment: Ok, I understand that point, so there is an alternative to remove that line or what should I do? It’s important that my js code works but I cant use ajax.